# How to play RTMP chunk?

Tags: h.264, wireshark, rtmp

i'm working with RTMP. I have captured RTMP packents in wireshark. Then a need take one RTMP chunk and play it. How i can do it? I try save chunk with hex editor in .h264 and play via VLC but it not help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUUfe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a single h264 chunk is useless. It must be combined with other chunks to make frames. To play h264 you need a minimum of SPS, PPS, and IDR. SPS and PPS are sent as part of the sequence header (different frame, different chunk) and a single chunk may not contain a complete tag.

Comment: Thank for your answer. It's very helpful advice

Comment: Each chunk start with 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 . Is it  NALU delimeter?

Comment: No. FLV does not use annexb.